# Why do requests fail on wp8 if system date is set to future?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, dotnet-httpclient

There is a behavior that is reproducable on windows phone devices and emulator. If you set the local date of the OS to a date in future like DateTime.Now + 10 days, a webbrowser control will fail with NavigationFailed-Event (without exception or reason details) and all HttpClientHandler AsyncGet-Requests will fail with 404 for unknown reason.

I would like to know why.

## Example

```
var req = await client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
if (req.IsSuccessStatusCode){...}
```

We have Dec 16th. I set the device date to Dec 26 and the return code is 404!

```
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 0.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Length: 0
}}
```

Same line of code with correct device date returns 200.

```
{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 0.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Mon, 16 Dec 2013 13:42:34 GMT
  ...
}}
```

This is reproducable setting a breakpoint at GetAsync. Setting the date of the WP8 to a future date, the result will be 404. If you step back and set the date to +/-4 days current date, 200 is returned as exprected.

### Reproducibility

**You can reproduce this with twitter app on a wp8 device.**

Start it and switch to settings - date+time and set it to a date in two weeks. Twitter app shows also an error message if you try to reload now.

Please don't answer, why to set the date to future. There are testers that will do so. ;)

Thanks!

## Update

**apologizes, probably i was not clear enough. So here are some more facts.**

*Same code is working using a local unit test with local date set to +2 weeks. (references a portable class library that encapsulates the httpclient as a service).
The servers and URIs are available all the time. 404 does mean "NOT FOUND" in .NET but this could be a enumeration mapping issue. I think "NOT FOUND" is misleading. 404 does not mean the same in all cases. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) for more information.
At second, the same pages and URIs for the HttpClientHandler are used in IOS and Android apps that work if you turn the date two weeks further.*

The behavior is also reproducable using the windows phone emulator. So my assumption is that this is a wp sdk design issue or a consecutive fault (caching, network stack) that is ending in an soft 404.

Comment: 404 is a server error not an app error. There is a high chance you will find an error message in the http response.

Comment: I know. That is why I posted the server response that is saying nothing than 404. Webbrowser control fails with empty Navigation Failed Event. Regards.

Comment: And that this is no server issue are showing apps like twitter that also do not work if you set the phone date to future.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear. Regards

Comment: Don't take the 404 seriously, Phone remaps lots of different errors to 404.  Even some that never make it to the wire.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP requests include a Date header.  There is a reasonable probability that some server side HTTP stacks will get upset if the Date you send is too far off the date on the server.  This is especially true for cases where there is some kind of token authentication that uses dates to prevent replay attacks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why doesn't happen this on Android and IOS devices connecting to the same servers? And why does internet explorer on WP8 is loading the pages also with a date set to future?

Comment: @dixus I really don't know.  Why not try running your request through Runscope and see if the error really does come from the server.  I have a MessageHandler here https://github.com/darrelmiller/RunscopeMessageHandler that will redirect your requests via runscope and you can see where the problem is really happening.